# @react-navigation/native useNavigation() jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

When I use jest to test my app, I find that if I use `useNavigation` in my hooks, an error will be reported, and the error message is as follows. I try to use mock myself, but it may be that I can't use mock, which leads to failure all the time. I write as follows:

```js
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => "NavigationNative");
```

[image]

test code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import {expect, it} from '@jest/globals';
import TargetItem from '../../containers/MyTask/TargetItem';
it('当使用默认值的情况', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<TargetItem />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

TargetItem Hooks code:

```js
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Pressable, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const TargetItem = ({routeParams, ...props}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const onPress = useCallback(() => {
    if (routeParams === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    navigation.navigate('', routeParams);
  }, [navigation, routeParams]);
  ......
}
```

when I run `jest test`:

```
Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

      23 |   targetValue,
      24 | }) => {
    > 25 |   const navigation = useNavigation();
         |                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party but you can mock it this way :

```js
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({
  useNavigation: () => ({ 
    navigate: jest.fn()
  }),
}))
```

Personaly, I did this in my `jest.setup.js` file which is executed before every tests so that I don't have to do it for every tests.